# cannot permamently set keyboard to qwertz Lubuntu 20.04 Focal

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, 20.04

Hi I set the keyboard layout to German Swiss QWERTZ and when I log out it goes to American English QWERTY.

Where can I change the settings so that it stays with German Swiss QWERTZ_

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.8/keyboard_and_mouse.html?highlight=keyboard%20layout is the Lubuntu manual page on setting for LXQt, however more details on your issue may help. Are you referring to a specific point (eg. before login and LXQt starts, eg. at `sddm` or key entry to unlock encryption? as LXQt settings won't have taken effect then as LXQt hasn't started).

Comment: If you're using full disk encryption (you've given little specifics if you're talking about encryption key issues, sddm or LXQt after signin) Lubuntu is using full disk encryption (main Ubuntu uses un-encrypted /boot/ so initial boot has more Ubuntu code available before un-encryption occurs..) Your issue no doubt relates to this issue - https://github.com/calamares/calamares/issues/1203 which is known (ie. non-QWERTY keyboard)   The work-arounds for this vary on your machine type.

Comment: I do -not- use full disk encryption

Comment: I currently cannot help, as I'm unsure if you're talking about after login (ie. LXQt session itself), the login page (ie. `sddm` before login assuming you've not changed it to something else), or `grub` (before kernel boot) which is why I asked for more details.